# Margin for Custom JButton - Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I've created a custom button for my application by extending Jbutton, and I've got it to paint the way I want, but for some reason, even though I call `setMargin()` in the constructor, the buttons have 0 margin, like so:

[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong in my code? How is it that standard JButtons have margins, but my custom buttons don't?

The java code for my button:

```
public class CToolbarButton extends JButton
{
        private static final Dimension SIZE = new Dimension(48, 48);

        private static final int MARGIN_VAL = 50;
        private static final Insets MARGIN = new Insets(MARGIN_VAL, MARGIN_VAL, MARGIN_VAL, MARGIN_VAL);

        private static final Color FILL_NORM = Color.GRAY;
        private static final Color FILL_ACTIVE = new Color(FILL_NORM.getRed()-25, FILL_NORM.getGreen()-25, FILL_NORM.getBlue()-25);

        private static final Color BORDER_NORM = Color.BLACK;
        private static final Color BORDER_ACTIVE = Color.YELLOW;

        public CToolbarButton()
        {
                super();
                setContentAreaFilled(false);
                setFocusable(false);
                setMargin(MARGIN);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
                if (getModel().isArmed())
                {
                        g.setColor(FILL_ACTIVE);
                }
                else
                {
                        g.setColor(FILL_NORM);
                }
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public void paintBorder(Graphics g)
        {
                if (getModel().isArmed())
                {
                        g.setColor(BORDER_ACTIVE);
                }
                else
                {
                        g.setColor(BORDER_NORM);
                }
                g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean contains(int x, int y)
        {
                return (x >= 0 &&
                                x <= getWidth() &&
                                y >= 0 &&
                                y <= getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize()
        {
                return SIZE;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize()
        {
                return SIZE;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMaximumSize()
        {
                return SIZE;
        }
}
```

Comment: *"I've created a custom button for my application by extending Jbutton,"*   Why?  What characteristics of a button does it have, that go beyond what is possible with a Swing `JButton`?  *"I've got it to paint the way I want, but.."*  Color me unsurprised there is a 'but'.

Comment: Because I want to custom paint it, and im not sure how to do that without creating a subclass...

Comment: What sort of custom painting?  Be specific..

Comment: I want to paint buttons the way photoshop or paint does, using icons or shading when clicked

Comment: Don't have Photoshop, but there is no part of the buttons in MS Paint that cannot be done with a standard `JButton` with an appropriate icon.

Comment: How does MSPaint (the new one in windows 7) get that gloss highlight around it though? That surely needs custom painting...

Comment: *"gloss highlight around it"*  What 'gloss' highlighting?  BTW - Did you try using the system PLAF?

Comment: I think I described it incorrectly, sorry... But it's this glow found around it when the button is pressed, like on the "stroke" button here:
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kZaspk5ogvw/TzWPC_nJF-I/AAAAAAAAFeI/WzSnUIkFtTU/s1600/paint.png

Comment: Are you referring to the 'eye dropper' button or the 'stroke' control?  BTW *Did you try using the system PLAF?*  Please take care to answer my questions!  I ask them for good reason and have little patience when it seems I am being ignored.

Comment: Sorry I didnt catch that last part, but yes I am currently using the system LAF. If i render JButtons normally they look like normal mac buttons. Is it possible to recreate that look using simple images?

Comment: *"they look like normal mac buttons."*  <head-desk />  I thought you were running this on Windows, in which case they should've appeared just like the ones in Paint.  So now I'll take a different tack.  Don't try to force the Windows look down the throats of your users on OS X & *nix.  Those users ***like*** the default look of their system, and detest when developers foist applications on them that look like Windows!

Comment: In that case, should I use images to add the icons for whatever tool the button represents, for example a brush on the "brush" tool button, etc? Because that seems like the way to go instead of writing custom buttons which is really provin difficult...

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remove this question tomorrow, seeing as how it was answered here in the comments. Thank you so much! This was quite a hurdle for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to override the paint method for the button, I'm just going to use images to simulate different looks for buttons instead.